# How to solve the recursive relation in Kalman filter?

Tags: recurrence-relations, signal-processing, recursive-algorithms, bayesian-network, kalman-filter

1. I was wondering how to solve [the Kalman filter's recursive
   equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#The_Kalman_filter) (also see the appendix at the end of this post) for the estimated state $\hat{\textbf{x}}_{n|n}$ at
   time $n$, over discrete times $k=1,\dots,n$? By solving the
   recursive equation, I mean to expand $\hat{\textbf{x}}_{n|n}$, for
   example, as linear combination of

   - the true initial state $\textbf{x}_0$,
   - the user-provided initial state $ \hat{\textbf{x}}_{0|0}$,
   - the control inputs up to time $n$, i.e.  $ \textbf{u}_k, k=1,\dots,n$,
   - the state noises up to time $n$, i.e.  $ \textbf{w}_k, k=1,\dots,n$,
   - the output noises up to time $n$, i.e.  $ \textbf{v}_k, k=1,\dots,n$
2. By substituting previous recursion into each recursion, starting
   from the initial one, I quickly realized the expanded form gets more
   and more complicated, and failed to observe some patterns common
   over the discrete times, in order to simplify the expanded form. So
   I wonder if it is always possible to solve a general recursive
   equation by observing some patterns? When possible, what are some ways to observe the patterns?

I have searched for a while in available books and on the internet, but haven't found one mentioning such expanded form for the estimated state by the Kalman filter. So I appreciate it if someone could provide some pointers as well.

Thanks and regards!

**Appendix**:

The Kalman filter tries to estimate the state $\textbf{x}_{k}$ from the outputs $\textbf{z}_{i}, i=1,\dots,k$ in the following [state-space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Underlying_dynamic_system_model):
$$
    \textbf{x}_{k} = \textbf{F}_{k} \textbf{x}_{k-1} + \textbf{B}_{k} \textbf{u}_{k} + \textbf{w}_{k} 
$$
$$
    \textbf{z}_{k} = \textbf{H}_{k} \textbf{x}_{k} + \textbf{v}_{k} 
$$
where the state noises and output noises have distributions:
$$\textbf{w}_k  \sim N(0, \textbf{Q}_k)$$
$$    \textbf{v}_{k} \sim N(0, \textbf{R}_k) $$

The [Kalman filter algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#The_Kalman_filter) gives

- a recursive equation for the estimated states $\hat{\textbf{x}}_{k|k}$ from previous one $\hat{\textbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}$, and
- a recursive equation for the estimated variance $\textbf{P}_{k|k}$ from previous one $\textbf{P}_{k-1|k-1}$, which is needed in the recursive equation for  $\hat{\textbf{x}}_{k|k}$.

> Initialize $ \hat{\textbf{x}}_{0|0}$ and $\textbf{P}_{0|0}$.
>
> At each iteration $k=1,\dots,n$
>
> **Predict**
>
> Predicted (a priori) state estimate    $$ \hat{\textbf{x}}_{k|k-1} =
>  \textbf{F}_{k}\hat{\textbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1} + \textbf{B}_{k}
>  \textbf{u}_{k} $$ 
>     Predicted (a priori) estimate covariance $$ 
>  \textbf{P}_{k|k-1} = \textbf{F}_{k} \textbf{P}_{k-1|k-1}
>  \textbf{F}_{k}^{\text{T}} + \textbf{Q}_{k}$$
>   **Update**
>
> Innovation or measurement residual     $$ \tilde{\textbf{y}}_k =
>  \textbf{z}_k - \textbf{H}_k\hat{\textbf{x}}_{k|k-1}$$ Innovation (or
>   residual) covariance   $$\textbf{S}_k = \textbf{H}_k
>  \textbf{P}_{k|k-1} \textbf{H}_k^\text{T} + \textbf{R}_k$$ Optimal
>   Kalman gain    $$\textbf{K}_k =
>  \textbf{P}_{k|k-1}\textbf{H}_k^\text{T}\textbf{S}_k^{-1}$$ 
>     Updated (a posteriori) state estimate      $$\hat{\textbf{x}}_{k|k} =
>  \hat{\textbf{x}}_{k|k-1} + \textbf{K}_k\tilde{\textbf{y}}_k$$ 
>     Updated (a posteriori) estimate covariance     $$\textbf{P}_{k|k} = (I -
>  \textbf{K}_k \textbf{H}_k) \textbf{P}_{k|k-1}$$

Comment: I was wrong previously. The output $\textbf{z}_k$ is involved in the recursive equation of $\hat{x}_{k|k}$, so $\hat{x}_{k|k}$ also depends on the true initial state $\textbf{x}_0$ through the state-space model.